# Are there any tools to visualize RabbitMQ bindings?

Tags: graphics, rabbitmq

It would be useful to have a tool that can programmatically generate a visual image of bindings between queues and exchanges.

Here's an example of the visual image that I'm expecting:
http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html

I've searched for some time, but haven't been able to find any options. Alternatively, if there isn't a direct solution, do you have any suggestion that might be useful for me to build my own?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an experiemental plugin that renders it to HTML5 Canvas:

http://www.rabbitmq.com/plugins.html

rabbitmq_management_visualiser

Comment: Unfortunately, this plugin is deprecated.